# Get user object from nearest matching username in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot send a DM to the user with the nearest matching username in the server. By nearest matching username I mean, if giving the bot a part of a username like "shin", it would find the nearest matching username like
"shinramen." This code I am providing only works for mentions or exact usernames of a user. I have tried using difflib but unfortunately couldn't get it to work. Is there any easier solution that I am missing?

```
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  user = await member.create_dm()
  await user.send('message goes here')
```

Comment: Just a note you don't need the `create_dm()` you can just `await member.send('Text here')`

Answer (score 1):

**In case you still need it, or if anyone else is looking for this.**

Use `discord.utils.find` to find the nearest member object. Here is an example of member converter for it:

```
class Member(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        try:
            member_converter = commands.MemberConverter()
            member = await member_converter.convert(ctx, argument)
        except commands.MemberNotFound:
            member = discord.utils.find(
                lambda m: m.name.lower().startswith(argument),
                ctx.guild.members
            )
        
        if member is None:
            raise commands.MemberNotFound(argument)

        return member
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to create a dm channel. Just use an `await member.send("Whatever msg")`

**PS:**
What do you mean by the nearest matching username? You'll have to **provide more details** because I don't see a point in that. **Discord** already **automatically** **does** **that** for you. Just press enter on the user you want to mention in discord. They will show you suggestions automatically. I'm pretty sure you no choice but to **mention** a member for the command to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why do you need this but you can get the names like this after that you can just whatever you want. I made more checks to see if the member has a nick in the guild or not.

Keep in mind this is for the author, you can change it for whatever you want.

```py
import difflib


@bot.command()
async def nearest(ctx):
    all_names = []
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if ctx.author == member:
            continue  # skip the author

        if member.nick:
            all_names.append(member.nick)
        else:
            all_names.append(member.name)

    if ctx.author.nick:
        close_names = difflib.get_close_matches(ctx.author.nick, all_names)
    else:
        close_names = difflib.get_close_matches(ctx.author.name, all_names)

    if close_names:
        await ctx.send(" - ".join(close_names))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are unique")
```

You can get the user for dm by using this.

```py
user = bot.get_member_named('Name here')
user.send("Found your brother")
```